# Posting Link to Facebook, appears as TEXT in Facebook wall. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am able to post the message to FB wall. but when there is a link in the message.
It appears only as whole text and not as a link.

I first tried with normal anchor tags and facebook meta tags. It is still the same.
How can i solve this ?

```
 protected void btnPostToWall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); 
        string strLink = "<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"" + Request.Url.ToString()  + "\"/>";

        strMessage = strName + " read the article " + strLink;
        parameters.message = strMessage;

        try
        {
            dynamic id = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = "Message posted successfully";
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending link at the end of `parameters.message` is not the way to post a link to Facebook wall using Graph API. What you ideally need is to pass it off as `parameters.properties` like this.

```
var url = Request.Url.ToString();
parameters.properties = new
{
    URL = new
    {
        text = url,
        href = url
    }
};
```

This will appear below the message as

> URL: http://mysite.com/